# VBA getElementById doesn't work for button

Tags: html, vba, getelementbyid

I am trying to go on a website, type a value in a textbox and then click the searchbutton to search for my value.
My Problem is, that i can't get the button element, to fire the click event.

VBA:

```
Dim i As Long
Dim objElement As Object
Dim objCollection As Object
 Dim result(2) As String
Dim timeout As Integer

Dim test As Object 'testweise

If IE Is Nothing = False Then
    IE.Quit
End If
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Visible = True


Start:

' Send the form data To URL As POST binary request
IE.navigate "https://www.bundesanzeiger.de/ebanzwww/wexsservlet"

' Wait while IE loading...
Do While IE.Busy
    DoEvents
    Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
Loop
IE.Document.getElementbyid("genericsearch_param.fulltext").Value = "Mielke"
IE.Document.getElementbyid("(page.navid=to_quicksearchlist)").Click
```

HTML

```
<div class="bbg"><input name="(page.navid=to_quicksearchlist)" type="submit" alt="Suchen" value="Suchen"></div>
```

the secont getElement call is supposed to get the button, the object is null though.
Does anyone know where i did a mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace:

```
IE.Document.getElementbyid("(page.navid=to_quicksearchlist)").Click
```

with:

```
Set x = IE.Document.GetElementsByName("(page.navid=to_quicksearchlist)")
x(0).Click
```

You need to look for the element by the **Name** not the **Id**

Comment: I get an error saying: "This object does not support this kind of method" (translation of a german error message)

Comment: Thanks a lot! That was the solution!

Answer (score 0):

You are using `getElementById`, which looks for the `id` of an element.

Your input button does not have any `id` attribute set, and this is why you cannot find it.

Add a value for the `id` attribute as so, and you will see it working:

```
<input id="xyz" ... />
```

Then:

```
IE.Document.getElementbyid("xyz").Click
```

Comment: getElementById is supposed to search for Id AND Name, at least that's what MSDN says:

getElementById 
Returns a reference to the first object with the specified value of the ID or NAME attribute. Here is the link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535862(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @Eych are you using IE8+?  From the documentation on MSDN: __Windows Internet Explorer 8 and later. In IE8 Standards mode, getElementById performs a case-sensitive match on the ID attribute only.__.  See here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536437%28v=vs.85%29.aspx.  Please give my code a try to see that it will solve your problem

Comment: Okay I see. That might be the problem. I can't try your code, because I can't add any attributes, since I am not the owner. I would need a function which searches for the name, which i have already written but it gives me an error when i try to use the .Click event.

Comment: In which case, you need to use `getElementsByName`, which returns a collection of elements (which may only have 1 item in it).  Take a look at the answer provided by **AnalystCave.com** which shows a solution using that method.  The appropiate MSDN article (which may also assist you) is https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536438%28v=vs.85%29.aspx.  Hope that helps

Comment: I already tried his solution but I get the error 91: "Object variable or with block variable not set". Btw thanks for the help so far!