# Button Not working with get element by id

Tags: html, vba

I need to download some inputs from a web page and until a certain point it works just fine. The problem is that in the case of one button, the get element by id function does not work (it doe snot give an error but the button does not do anything). The purpose of the button is to move a selected item from a list to the left to one to the right.

Below is the VBA code:

```
 Dim ie As Object
    Set ie = New InternetExplorerMedium
       ie.Visible = True
         ie.Navigate2 RepLnk1
         Do While ie.Busy
            Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
         Loop
   '.....a pretty big code that works.....'

    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:10"))
    ie.document.getElementById("id_mstr51").Click
```

Below is the HTML code of the button

```
<div class="mstrToolButtonRounded" id="id_mstr51" style="display: block; background-position: left center;"><img title="Alle hinzufügen" onmouseout="mstr.behaviors.ToolButtonRounded.unhover(this.parentNode)" style="background-position: left center; cursor: pointer;" class="mstrBGIcon_tbAddAll" src="../images/1ptrans.gif" onmouseover="mstr.behaviors.ToolButtonRounded.hover(this.parentNode)" onclick="var v = mstr.$obj('id_mstr51'); return (v.get('enabled')) ? mstr.$obj('id_mstr51').fireCommands() : false;" align="absmiddle"></div>
```

Please do not set this question as duplicate (as it was set before), because I tried all the solutions I could find (including the suggested post) and none worked.

Comment: Hi! It is a good idea to mention which solution from the duplicate question have you tried and how have you tried it - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31201788/vba-getelementbyid-doesnt-work-for-button

Comment: `51` seems to be generated dynamically. Try this `Dim HTML as HTMLDocument : Set HTML = ie.document : HTML.querySelector("[id^='id_mstr'] img").Click` if your browser supports `.querySelector()`. I suppose you are using `IE9` or later version.

Comment: Is this an internal/login based url or one that can be shared to help us to help you?